# send model with ajax to controller, asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I wondering what is the best way to accomplish this task:
In my index method I'm either searching or filtering or just taking
data from my db. Then I send n items to view. If there more than n items
I need some paging to be done. As I understand I can query my db again
filter or search and take next n elements or I can somehow persist all
my data(filtered or data received after search query) and just
take n next elements from it. As I understand session is not the best way
to accomplish it, so instead of IEnumerable of this class

```
public class CatalogModel
{
    public string Price;
    public string deviceName;
    public string imgUrl;
}
```

I've decided to use this class

```
public class CatalogView
{
    public IEnumerable<CatalogModel> Catalog;
    public IEnumerable<Device> Devices;

    public CatalogView(IEnumerable<CatalogModel> catalog = null, IEnumerable<Device> devices = null)
    {
        Catalog = catalog;
        Devices = devices;
    }
}
```

I wand to keep all my data in

```
 public IEnumerable<Device> Devices
```

this field and each time send it to controller,
but I don't know how can I access it from javascript so I can post it back 
with ajax.

Is it possible to do it such way and will it be more efficient than
querying each time my db.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. you should first make your action in the controller that accept CatalogView object.
2. To create an object simllar to your C# object you can use this line

   ```
   var obj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new CatalogView())
   ```
3. Modify your code to

   ```
   public class CatalogView
   {
       public IEnumerable<CatalogModel> Catalog;
       public IEnumerable<Device> Devices;

       public CatalogView(IEnumerable<CatalogModel> catalog = null, IEnumerable<Device> devices = null)
       {
           Catalog = catalog;
           Devices = devices;
       }

       public CatalogView ()
       {
           Catalog = new List<CatalogModel>();
           Devices = new List<Device>();
       }
   }
   ```

   and make all your public fields public properties in order to be convert to and from JSON
   4.for the javascript you can use the following  code snippet

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: "@Url.Action("YourActionName","ControllerName")",
       data: JSON.stringify(obj),
       contentType: "application/json",
       success: function (details) {
           //execute on success
       }
   });
   ```

you should use the http://www.json.org/js.html in order to convert your object to json

Comment: the thing is when I've tried this, I had cycle error(I'm using entity framework). But I used @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Devices)

Comment: Maybe device class has a recursive reference to itself or another class